# PHP mPDF - How to create HTML footer using CSS styles for part of footer?

Tags: php, mpdf

I use mPDF to create my PDF files. The problem is with footer, where I must to use CSS styles (bold text) for part of footer.

Effect what I need:

> **Phone:** 888-555-111, **E-mail:** test@test.pl, **Fax:** 666-555-666

But I can't create this footer into mPDF because I have to declare CSS tags for all footer content, not for part of footer. So I can use bold text for full footer:

```
<pagefooter name="MyFooter1" line="1" footer-style="font-weight: bold;" content-center="Phone: 888-555-111, E-mail: test@test.com, Fax: 666-555-666" />
<setpageheader name="MyHeader1" value="on" show-this-page="1" />
<setpagefooter name="MyFooter1" value="on" />
```

Result:

**Phone: 888-555-111, E-mail: test@test.com, Fax: 666-555-666**

But how to use this CSS styles only for part of footer?

Thanks.

Comment: You need HTML, not CSS here. `<b>Phone:</b> 888-555-111, <b>E-mail:</b> test@test.pl [...]`

Comment: I tried this way. It doesn't work too. Effect is: bPhone:b 888-555-111 (...).

Comment: Did you used proper method for that: https://mpdf.github.io/reference/mpdf-functions/sethtmlfooter.html

Comment: This method adding footer for all pages into document. I want to create this footer only for first page.